# PDO Insert Into DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've seen so many tutorials with so many different ways to insert using PDO. None of them seem to work for me. Can't seem to get mine to send to the database. I have no issue connecting and retreiving the data using FETCH but can't seem to post this data.

Any help with getting my post to work and redirect using the header or meta refresh would be nice. I am $_POST from an html form. Connecting to the db works just fine but can't get the data in.

```
   $hostdb = 'myremoteip';
   $namedb = 'cpdemo';
   $userdb = 'root';
   $passdb = 'mypassword';

   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);

   if(isset($_POST['fname'])) {

         $fname = $_POST['fname'];
         $lname = $_POST['lname'];
         $title = $_POST['title'];
         $photo = $_POST['photo'];

   $stmt = "INSERT INTO row_users (fname,lname,title,photo) 
         VALUES (:first,:last,:title,:photo)";

   $q = $conn->prepare($stmt);
   $results = $q->execute(array(
        ":first"=>$fname,
        ":last"=>$lname,
        ":title"=>$title,
        ":photo"=>$photo
    ));
    echo 'User Added<br/>';
    }

      header ('Location:../insertUser.html');
    exit();
```

Comment: Here goes the only tutorial you really need: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: Or, more specific to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858

Comment: Your Common Sense... great tut on PDO. Im completely new to PDO prepared statements so this looks very beneficial. Im going to give it a try now...

Comment: What you need at the moment is error reporting. As your code seems okay - so, there can be some issue with database. Or, even if there is any issue with code - it is WAY simpler to find it, guided by error message

Comment: So would you suggest adding: (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) to my connection? it is connecting but not inserting.

Comment: i actually did have: catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
  } but there is no error or anything and the header doesnt even execute.

Comment: please follow either tutorial. Yes, you need PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE set. No, you don't need  catch. You also have to be able to see PHP errors in general

Comment: ok got it. let me give it a try...

Comment: @MizAkita I tested your code "as is", and it worked fine. The only thing I can tell that could be the issue is, that your insert won't happen unless it meets the conditional statement you've set `if(isset($_POST['fname']))` --- Check to see if your HTML form's elements are indeed named? I.e. `<input type="text" name="fname">` etc. If one of those are not not named or has a typo, then your whole query will fail. Show us the HTML form that you're using in your question in order to rule anything out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you submit your response as an answer. Changing if(isset( to $_POST['first'] did it... my form now sends.

Comment: oh, and changing the POST values to my input names did it as well. what i had listed were my column names. Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: @MizAkita I posted it below. Am glad the matter got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by OP, comment leading to an answer (to close the question and marked as solved).

I tested your code "as is", and it worked fine.

The only thing I can tell that could be the issue is, that your insert won't happen unless it meets the conditional statement you've set `if(isset($_POST['fname']))`

Check to see if your HTML form's elements are indeed named?

I.e. `<input type="text" name="fname">` etc. If one of those are not not named or has a typo, then your whole query will fail.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to understand that **there is no such thing** like "PDO Insert Into DB"

There is INSERT query, irrelevant to PDO but regular to database you are using.
And there is PDO prepared statement, irrelevant to query type. You have to follow exactly the same pattern, no matter if it insert or delete.

So - all you need is just a tutorial on PDO prepared statements. That's all. Preferably one that teach you to enable error reporting in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding parameter before passing it to execute, like for example in the below code

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: Would the execute work without binding the parameters?

Comment: why you're asking me? why not to read execute() manual page? it's the only reliable source, mind you.